# Can I save Objects, Object Collections in a Laravel 5 Session?

Tags: php, object, laravel, save, session-variables

Is it possible to save php Objects, object collections in laravel 5 Session?

I was trying but I get error on this

```
Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed vendor/illuminate/session/Store.php line 255

Session::put('my_php_object', $obj );
Session::save();


public function onRun()
{

    $this->addCss('assets/css/custom.css');
    $this->socialite_providers = $this->page['socialite_providers'] =$this->providersList();

    //check for provider param in url
    if($provider = $this->param('provider')){

        $this->setSessionProvider($provider);
        $this->provider = $provider;
        $this->callback_url = preg_replace('~.*\K:(.*)~s','',Request::root().$this->page->url);
        $this->request = $this->createRequest($provider);


        Session::save();
        return $this->request->redirect();

    }

    //Authorize user if Request has code
    if(Request::has('code')){

        if(!$this->getSession())
            return;

        //reuse save session

    }

}

public function createRequest($provider)
{
    $instance = Socialite::driver($provider);
    $init = $this->injectCredentials($instance, $provider);

    $this->setSession($init);
    return $init;
}

public function injectCredentials($instance, $provider){
    $credential = $this->providerData($provider)->toArray();
    $instance = new $instance
    (
        Request::instance(),
        $credential['client_id'],
        $credential['client_secret'],
        $this->callback_url
    );

    return $instance;
}

public function setSession($init)
{
    if(Session::has('socialite_object'))
        Session::forget('socialite_object');


    Session::put('socialite_object', $init );

}
```

Comment: Did you try serialize($obj)? It probably won't work but anyway.

Comment: I've been trying won't work than I get Serialize Closure error

Comment: I have successfully saved objects and collections in Laravel to the session without issue.  I would be suspicious that maybe you are using '$this' somewhere and actually getting something you aren't intending.

Answer (score 1):

You could always store the JSON representation of the object you tried to store.

However, I've heard it's generally a good idea not to store large things in the Session, is there anyway you could manage by storing something else? If you are storing an object from the DB, you could store the Id and recover the object with a query.